# No write access to gvfs smb shares in 16.04 (known bug -- is there a workaround?)

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, gvfs

In Ubuntu 16.04 gvfs links to smb shares do not give you write access to the files on the share. This bug is [already reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/gvfs/+bug/1598183).

Since most programs do not give you the opportunity to browse to the smb share directly (e.g. in a "save file as" dialog), this makes it basically impossible to edit files on an smb share (without copying them back and forth between the share and your local drive).

Unfortunately the importance of that bug is only set to "medium" and it has not been fixed for more than half a year already.

Until we see a fix for it -- is there a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The "workaround" is to mount the share as [CIFS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939973.aspx):

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<remote_account>,uid=$USER,gid=$USER,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644 //server/share /path/to/mount/point
```

If the system says that it doesn't know about CIFS then install `cifs-utils`.

"Workaround" is in scare quotes because I consider this to be normal and natural way to access a SMB share.

Comment: thanks. kind of obvious now ;) i was thinking "workaround" in the sense that i can keep the gvfs-mounts. for me they have the advantage that i can automount them without needing to put my credentials in a text-file (even if only root-accessible) because they are saved in the "keychain".

Comment: hey, thanks for the reminder ;) since this question has not been open for too long, i will not accept an answer yet (btw: this also gives you the chance of gathering more upvotes). also, as i pointed out in my comment, it was not really what i was looking for. so i will see whether somebody can point out a solution keeping the gvfs mounts